# Declaring dynamic bash variable with a function

Tags: bash

I want to create a function in a bash script that declares a variable and value supplied to the function to be re-used later.

```
function format_msg {
  declare "$1"="[ \033[00;32m$2 OK\033[0m ]"
}

format_msg "foo" "bar"
echo "${!foo}"
```

This is a returning a null value

Comment: If you declare a variable inside a function it becomes local to that function.

Answer (score 4):

The `declare` builtin declares a *local* variable (using dynamic scope); so the variable disappears when the function returns.

If you have a sufficiently recent version of Bash, one option is to use `printf` with the `-v var` option (which saves to a variable instead of writing to standard output):

```
function format_msg {
  printf -v "$1" "%s" "[ \033[00;32m$2 OK\033[0m ]"
}
```

(That said, I do agree with CMPS's suggestion that you simply change your function so that it *only* handles the formatting, and lets the calling code handle the assignment. The general idea in Unix programming is "do one thing and do it well".)

---

**Edited to add:** I should also point out two other issues with your code, that you'll run into once you fix the above:

- Unless your `echo` is defined specially (e.g. you've enabled support for backslash-escapes), it doesn't look like you're ever processing the `\033` so as to get actual color formatting. So I think you probably really want

  ```
  printf -v "$1" "[ \033[00;32m%s OK\033[0m ]" "$2"
  ```

  with `printf` handling the `\033`.
- `"${!foo}"` will interpret the *contents* of `$foo` as a new variable-name, and then expand to the results of *that* variable; I'm pretty sure that you just want

  ```
  echo "$foo"
  ```

Comment: `printf -v` was introduced in `bash` 3.1, although it couldn't assign to a slot of an array until `bash` 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Using the declare inside the function makes it local to the function.

Try this instead:

```
function format_msg {
  echo "[ \033[00;32m$1 OK\033[0m ]"
}

foo=$(format_msg "bar")
echo $foo
```

Answer (score 1):

`declare`, by default, creates a local variable. Starting with `bash` 4.2, you can use the `-g` option to create a global variable instead.

```
function format_msg {
  declare -g "$1=[ \033[00;32m$2 OK\033[0m ]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been said already, your code fails in this specific case because bash makes a variable (as if the command) `local` (has been issued) when declare is used. That is equivalent to ksh's `typeset`, as well as zsh's `typeset`, and its alternative forms `declare`, `integer`, `local` and `readonly` (but not `export`).

Also, you are trying to print via an indirect form `echo "${!foo}"`. That will not print the value of `$foo` but the value of a variable (if it exists) which name is the value of `$foo`.

Using declare inside the function is possible if this form is used (for bash 4.2+):

```
declare -g "$1"="[ \033[00;32m$2 OK\033[0m ]"
```

The most basic way to make the assignment without using `declare` for older bash version (and in general for most shells) is the always worrisome eval (if the value of `$1` or `$2` has any chance of having been set by an attacker (or external user)):

```
eval "$1"='"[ \033[00;32m'"$2"' OK\033[0m ]"'
```

Of course, that will assign the string `[ \033[00;32mbar OK\033[0m ]` to `$foo`, which doesn't seem to be the intended goal.

This simple change should correctly assign the intended escaped characters to the variable:

```
eval "$1"=$'"[ \033[00;32m'"$2"$' OK\033[0m ]"'
```

Which will change to Green for `bar OK` and then reset the color setting.

To remove the risk of eval, we need to use something else.

For ksh 93+ and bash 4.3+ we may use `nameref`s (bash form used):

```
declare -n ref=$1
ref=$'"[ \033[00;32m'"$2"$' OK\033[0m ]"'
```

Or bash printf's -v option:

```
printf -v "$1" '"[ \033[00;32m%s OK\033[0m ]"' "$2"
```

In which case the interpretation of the escape codes (`\033`) is done by printf.

Once the variable contains the required value, is better to use printf to print it instead of echo, and no indirection is needed:

```
#!/bin/bash

format_msg() {
    printf -v "$1" '"[ \033[00;32m%s OK\033[0m ]"' "$2"
}

format_msg "foo" "bar"
printf 'var foo=%s\n' "${foo}"
```